# Set variable value when breakpoint is hit

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is there a way to determine if Eclipse has reach the breakpoint then change the variable value?

For example

```
public class Test {

static boolean isDebug = false;

 static void A() {
  System.out.println(isDebug);
 }

 static void B() {
  System.out.println(isDebug);
 }

 static void C() {
  System.out.println(isDebug);
 }

public static void main(String args[]) {
 A();
 B();
 C();
}
```

The result would be:

```
false
false
false
```

What I need is the

```
static boolean isDebug = setTrueIfBreakpointWasHit;
```

So when if I set breakpoint on the B(); method the result would be:

```
false
true
true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional breakpoints for this. If you return false, the execution is not paused.

[image: conditional breakpoint]

Right-click on the breakpoint and select 'Properties'.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, this solution is solving a problem but it require to set up the conditional breakpoint every time if adding a new breakpoint. I wonder if there is possibility to set the value automatically so the newly added breakpoint would work like conditional.